# How (or is it necessary) to convert a Javascript Object to Dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dojo

The following codes just try to clone a row and reset the id of the cloned:

```
rowTemplate = j('#component .form-list:first-child').clone();
var newRow = dojo.clone(rowTemplate);
dojo.attr(newRow, 'id', newRowId);
```

However, from firebug the third line give me

```
TypeError: node.setAttribute is not a function (dojo.js)
```

from debugging i can see the newRow is an Object(object[#row.class]), so the question is: How (or is it necessary) to convert a Javascript Object to Dom to make it available to dom functions?

Comment: Can you show us the exact value of the `newRow`? `object[#row.class]` only seems to be some stringification

Comment: Why are you first cloning with jQuery, and then again with dojo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a jQuery object with a dojo method, you have to convert the jQuery object into a dom element collection. This can be done using `.get()`

```
rowTemplate = j('#component .form-list:first-child').clone();
var newRow = dojo.clone(rowTemplate.get(0));
dojo.attr(newRow, 'id', newRowId);
```

disclaimer: I'm not familiar with dojo methods.